# React native : Redux call dispatch function for taking data from different component and use

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am working on react native application. I have one parent component and two child component in that. in child one i have a long list and i can select multiple item on click and for that i add all selected item in array one by one on click.

now submit button is in another child component. on that submit button i need that array.

This is like in whats app we can select multiple chat conversation for delete and then press delete from header component for delete all selected conversation.I have to implement same thing

I am thinking to use redux for that but not sure that on which action i will call store.dispatch(). can i call it from different component which store variable from other component.. as given

on Click of list item i am creating array but if same time i will call dispatch then it will not be a good idea because on select each and every item it will call dispatch.

is it possible to call store.dispatch from header component on click submit button and it will take that array from list component.

i want to send selectedItems array in store so i can use this on submit

at list page code is like

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
   selectedItems : []  
}
```

on selecting each item i call _selectedItem

```
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#556b2f' onPress={() => {this._selectedItem(person)}}>
```

_selectedItem function defined as push item in array

```
 _selectedItem(person) {
  console.log('Selected item '+person.first_name);
  this.state.item=person;
  this.state.selectedItems.push(this.state.item);
  console.log('Selected item '+this.state.selectedItems.length);
}
```

I am new to redux so no idea it may be a basic thing.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly dispatch to the redux store after selecting all of the list items.  From my limited experience, it sounds like a better architecture than what you have so far would be the following:

The parent component stores the state, and functions for updating the state, and the two children are stateless (taking the state variables from the parent as props).  In other words, the parent component would include the following:

```
state = {
  selectedItems: []
}

onPress() {
  // Dispatch action with this.state.selectedItems
}

_selectItem(person) {
  let newSelectedItems = [...this.state.selectedItems, person];
  this.setState({ selectedItems: newSelectedItems });
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
       <ListComponent 
         selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems} 
         _selectItem={this._selectItem.bind(this)} />
       <ButtonComponent
         onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I hope this helps get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @jason Evans. But situation quite different. Here in my case 
Parent is mainContainer. It has two child headerContainer and contentContainer. Content container has three childContainer as three listview on Three different tab.. As example i have given whatsapp page. Chat list, Status Lists and Call List, 
and select button on Header Container so hierarchy is in this way,

so in grand parent there is not selected items variable.. can you please explain in this way

Comment: Regardless of how many children, grandchildren, etc the parent has, you should be able to continue to keep all of the logic in the parent.  To be clear, I understand that the grandparent does not currently keep the selecteditems variable; I'm proposing that you move the selecteditems variable to the grandparent variable, and pass it down to the children (and grandchildren) as a prop.  And that way, the parent is holding all of the state information and can use that when dispatching an action triggered by the button.

Comment: In the render method above, you can see that I'm proposing passing down the selectedItems from the grandparent as a prop to ListComponent, and then passing the method selectitem as well to the ListComponent ....does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks Jason. 
Its worked without using redux, i got idea from your response. Thanks.
I just create one more order array as states at parent and passed this to child and child to grand child. 
On selecting each item  assigened 
order= selecteditems
And this way i got order at parent...

Yes, array will change on each select but not dispatching on every selection so hope i will not be bad idea.. 
Now on submit on parent i can dispatch oder array so i cant that if required...